# Display Facebook statuses on website

Tags: facebook

I am looking for a way to display all status updates from my Facebook page onto my website, along with relevant links and images. I do not want the user to have to be Facebook logged in to view these statuses

I'd have thought this would be quite easy to achieve but I don't see any ready-made applications or plugins that suit my needs. Anything that I have seen requires the Like button or for the user to login.

So far, the only way that I've found is using the JSON Graph API, which although seems simple enough to use, still requires effort to display images, links etc. [See this tutorial](http://johndoesdesign.com/blog/2011/php/adding-a-facebook-news-status-feed-to-a-website/)

Can anyone advise me of a better solution to this please?

Comment: How about the [Like Box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/)?

Comment: Yes the Like Box looks good as it does not require you to click Like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at http://www.neosmart.de/social-media/facebook-wall? It's pretty slick and a couple of versions in.  For the token you could create a Facebook app and use the app token to access the content that way there would be no user login required.

Comment: This looks exactly like what I was looking for